# left/right bitwise shifts - why do we shift by byte length

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have been reading this blog about bit manipulation in networking packages. I have this code and I am seeing that its reading in an integer which is typically 4 bytes long (32 bits)

```java
public int readInt() {
    return (pData[caret++] & 0xff) << 24 | (pData[caret++] & 0xff) << 16
            | (pData[caret++] & 0xff) << 8 | pData[caret++] & 0xff;
}
```

Why are we moving by 8, 16 and 24 when reading in an integer value? What is the goal and what does it achieve?

Comment: What tutorial are you following and why does it not explain that part? Have you tried this code with a given input and looked at what it actually produces? What is `pData`?

Comment: It sets the correct [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). It seems like pData contains the most significant byte on the lowest index.

Comment: ^^ Be aware that there is no "unsigned" in java, so sometimes you may come across `long` being used for an unsigned int from network.

Comment: @Fildor `char` is unsigned in Java

Comment: @phuclv that's a special case, but yes. On the other hand, I haven't seen char being used for unsigned numbers ...

Answer (score 1):

That is because pData is a byte array. What readInt() does is pack 4 bytes into an integer then return the result. Because an integer is 4 bytes, by `((value & 0xFF) << 24)` will set for the 1'st slot, `((value & 0xFF) << 16)` for the 2'nd slot, `((value & 0xFF) << 8)`  for the 3'rd slot and `(value & 0xFF)` for the last slot. And to merge these four values into one (that in this case is an integer), bitwise OR ( `|`) must be performed between each value. If pData is indeed an integer array, thats probably because it wants to use unsigned integers (0 - 255). So what readInt() does is pack 8 LSB (least significant bits) for each int (up to 4 integers) into an integer then return the result.